# MySQL seems to be changing the information given from Python

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I'm using the MySQLdb Python package to connect to the database, and some of the fields in my table do update correctly, but many of them seem to default to a certain value. I'm using a stored procedure called "submit_results", and it leads to an update procedure, which updates a students marks, by using the exam number as an index.

```
cursor.execute("call s4u155_examcorrector.submit_results({},{},{});".format(str(exam_number),str(marks),str(markedstring)))
```

I have the Python output the examnumber and marks that were given  for a question (for debugging). As you can see, exam number 7 got 0222202222 (which is a string/varchar)

```
Exam Number: 7 
Marks: 0222202222
```

The MySQL table on the other hand outputs:

```
7
222202222
```

Any ideas as too why exactly this is happening? Thank you in advance.
*Edit: marks is a Varchar(100)*

Comment: What is the type of `marks` before you do `str(marks)` inside of your call to `.format()`?  What's the code for the stored procedure `s4u155_examcorrector.submit_result`?  What code produced that Python debugging output?  What code produced the MySQL output?

Comment: marks is a float before a string, whereas the marksstring is a string already, the marksstring is where the issue is occuring. The code producing the output in python is just `print(exam_number) print(markedstring)`. I'm unable to get the stored procedure as I do not have permissions on this server to read them, although it does work most times.

Comment: What datatypes is your stored procedure expecting?  Your are passing your string arguments without single quotes which means they will be passed as numeric data.

Comment: it's expecting a varchar, but I will change to single quotes, thanks

Comment: Also, [the docs show](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/calling-mysql-stored-procedures-python/) that stored procedures should be called differently.  It should be something like `cursor.callproc('s4u155_examcorrector.submit_results', [exam_number, marks, markedstring])`.  Doing it your way you still need single quotes around string arguments `cursor.execute("call s4u155_examcorrector.submit_results('{}',{},'{}');".format(str(exam_number),str(marks),str(markedstring)))`.

Comment: I will attempt the second method, and thank you very much for reference to that I never thought about python procedure functions.

Comment: Thank you so much putting the '' around the field fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the '' around the curly braces in the Python fixed the issue, as SQL was seeing the input as a number and cutting off the zero.